# Python Google Map API gives OSM_type that does not match documentation

Tags: python-3.x, google-maps-api-3

I was using [Google's Map API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/maps-static/intro) to extract address information for latitude and longitude coordinates from within Python.  As shown in the code below, there is an attribute called `osm_type` that I believe is "open street maps type".  But when I google for documentation, I find just "type" and all the lists I am finding do not include "way" as one of the expected answers to type.  Does anyone know where I can get a list of types that are valid for `osm_type`?

Code:

```
from geopy.geocoders import Nominatim
geolocator = Nominatim()
from geopy.exc import GeocoderTimedOut
import time

lat = 43.2335233435383   
lon = -70.9108497973799
location = geolocator.reverse(str(lat) + ", " + str(lon), timeout=10)
print(location.raw)
```

Output:

```
{'address': {'city': 'Dover',
  'country': 'United States of America',
  'country_code': 'us',
  'county': 'Strafford County',
  'house_number': '155',
  'postcode': '03820',
  'road': 'Long Hill Road',
  'state': 'New Hampshire'},
 'boundingbox': ['43.233423343538',
  '43.233623343538',
  '-70.91094979738',
  '-70.91074979738'],
 'display_name': '155, Long Hill Road, Dover, Strafford County, New Hampshire, 03820, United States of America',
 'lat': '43.2335233435383',
 'licence': 'Data © OpenStreetMap contributors, ODbL 1.0. https://osm.org/copyright',
 'lon': '-70.9108497973799',
 'osm_id': '18868744',
 'osm_type': 'way',
 'place_id': '201786637'}
```

Comment: I seem to have duplicated your problem.  Help documentation lists "type" not "osm_type" and "way" is not listed.  Is it possible something changed in the API, that osm_type is documented as "type" and "way" is either a data mistake or is depricated but not listed in depricated section?  See this URL:  https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell, the specific code you are using does not support returning the `type`.  However, running a few spot checks with your code, inputting other latitudes and longitudes, I found that a McDonalds in NY produced an `osm_type` of "node" instead of "way" and "way" comes up a lot.  I got "node" with: Latitude=40.730949, Longitude=-74.001083.

If instead of checking Google Maps documentation, you look at [Open Street Maps documentation](https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Elements), you will see that this field is most likely defining the type of data rather than the type of address.  These types are defined by the given URL:

- node
- way
- relation

That should answer what "way" means for you in this context.

Accessing the [type](https://developers.google.com/places/supported_types) as defined for the Google Maps API will probably require a different piece of code (if its possible).  The command you are using does not appear to have that field in its output.

This page on location [searches](https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search), would seem to indicate that "type" is a field used in a location search to narrow down what you are looking for.  These types do not appear to be a part of the API call you are using.